# Ошибка, когда экземпляры двух классов указывают друг на друга

Tags: c#, wpf

Столкнулся с проблемой в программе на WPF. Есть класс главной формы и класс, который создал вручную. Методы этих классов ссылаются друг на друга, поэтому в обоих классах создал экземпляры друг на друга.

После создания экземпляров стало выдавать ошибку выполнения.

```
class A // Класс главной формы
{
    B objB = new B();
};

class B // Созданный вручную класс
{
    A objA = new A(); // Здесь выдает ошибку
};
```

Comment: А какую ошибку выдаёт, нам рекомендуется угадать самим? Думаю, что это `StackOverflowException` — подумайте сами, почему.

Comment: @VladD Да, `StackOverflowException`, забыл написать

Comment: `new` создаёт **новый** экземпляр класса. НОВЫЙ! то есть `A` создаёт новый `B`, в процессе этого `B` создаёт новый `A`, в процессе этого `A` создаёт новый `B` и т. д. А вам надо совсем не это.

Comment: Подумайте, какой из объектов должен создать другой. **Оба** они это делать не могут никак.

Comment: Думаю нужно использовать new только внутри класса главной формы. Но вот только если в классе, который я создал, создать экземпляр так `A a;` то выдает предупреждение при компиляции `'InformationPanels.mainWindow' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null` и ошибку выполнения `System.NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A // Класс главной формы
{
    B objB;

    public A()
    {
        objB = new B(this);
    }
};

class B // Созданный вручную класс
{
    A objA;

    public B(A objA)
    {
        this.objA = objA;
    }
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, так заработало